# Multiple user notification in firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can send single push notification to a multiple user(Android or IOS) at a time using my php back-end. But now i need to send different message to different users at a time. How can i achieve it?

Comment: "*i need to send different message to different users at a time*" - then you simply have to send a different request per user. I'm not sure what you're looking for here.

Comment: can i send a user list and respective notification?

Comment: If you mean sending a list of users and their respective messages in one request, then no. There is currently no such feature.